# Error:(18) No resource identifier found for attribute 'met_maxCharacter' in package

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm new to android studio and I'm currently using the version 3.0.1. This is one of many errors I am encountering, and I'm unable to understand where I'm missing out on a resource file. Here are my XML files: 
First file is the home page, second is the sign in page and third is the sign up page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    tools:context="com.aarya.tejas.aaryafirst.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="172dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logof4"
            android:contentDescription="@null"/>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/slogan"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:text="@string/sign_up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the sign in page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    tools:context="com.aarya.tejas.aaryafirst.SignIn">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/editPhone"
            android:hint="@string/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:text="7007643323"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:inputType="phone"
            app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_maxCharacter="11"
            app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
            />
        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/editPassword"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:text="nidhip123"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_maxCharacter="11"
            app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the sign up page:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    tools:context="com.aarya.tejas.aaryafirst.SignUp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/editPhone"
            android:hint="@string/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:text="7007643323"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:inputType="phone"
            app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_maxCharacter="11"
            app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
            />
        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/editName"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Nidhi Pathak"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_maxCharacter="11"
            app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
            />
        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:id="@+id/editPassword"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
            android:text="nidhip123"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_maxCharacter="11"
            app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
            app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:text="@string/sign_up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please do help me with this, as I'm really new to android development and just wanted to explore :)

Comment: app:met_maxCharacter="11" it is saying there is no property like this.

Comment: In the error message it didn't really show met_maxCharacter="11". I know that I'm supposed to just remove something as it is a property, but what is it that I should remove?

Comment: you should remove this line app:met_maxCharacter="11". What does it do anyway? Do you know about this?

Comment: Sorry, I was using a youtube tutorial and it mentioned it. I tried searching for this property, but never really found it so I thought it was compulsory. Thank you anyway :)